# Tableview scrolls jumps when changing text field focus

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, uitextfield

I have a static tableview that has one, large cell with several textfields. Whenever I select a new text field the scroll will bounce all the way to the bottom, up high, then come back down to where the newly selected textfield is. Why is it doing this? Should I move each textfield to it's own individual cell, or is there a method to override that can fix this?

Comment: Could you either post some code or maybe upload your project and post a link here and I´ll try to help you.

Comment: @Cody harness Please share as much as possible. Possible that textfield width is greater than the table column width.